# How to load multiple routes in index file using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a following index file -

```
<BrowserRouter>
 <Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={Home}
  <Route element={Navigation}
</Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

I have multiple routes which I have to load So For that I have written a component:

```
 const Navigation = () => {
   <>
      <Route path="/not-available-primary" element={NotAvaliable}/>
      <Route path="/not-available-Secondary" element={Avaliable}/>
      <Route path="/available-primary" element={Primary}/>
      <Route path="/available-Secondary" element={Secondary}/>
      <Route path="/direct-debit-primary" element={DirectDBB}/>
      <Route path="/direct-debit-secondary" element={DirectDBBSecondary}/>
   </>
  }
```

But here, it does not render the component and gives no routes matched for location.
How do I fix this ?

Comment: react-router new version has "element" replacement to a component.

Comment: Yes, I updated the quesiton but still it has the same issue

Comment: You have no closing tags for two of the routes.

Answer (score 1):

You have to give a Component to the element prop, like this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
 <Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
  <Route path="/*" element={<Navigation />} />
</Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

and

```
const Navigation = () => {
   return (<>
      <Route path="/not-available-primary" element={<NotAvaliable />}/>
      <Route path="/not-available-Secondary" element={<Avaliable />}/>
      <Route path="/available-primary" element={<Primary />}/>
      <Route path="/available-Secondary" element={<Secondary />}/>
      <Route path="/direct-debit-primary" element={<DirectDBB />}/>
      <Route path="/direct-debit-secondary" element={<DirectDBBSecondary />}/>
   </>)
  }
```

or

```
<BrowserRouter>
 <Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
  <Route path="/*">
      <Route path="not-available-primary" element={<NotAvaliable />}/>
      <Route path="not-available-Secondary" element={<Avaliable />}/>
      <Route path="available-primary" element={<Primary />}/>
      <Route path="available-Secondary" element={<Secondary />}/>
      <Route path="direct-debit-primary" element={<DirectDBB />}/>
      <Route path="direct-debit-secondary" element={<DirectDBBSecondary 
      />}/>
  </Route>
</Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Note that in the seconds solution (nested routes) I erased the "/".

Documentation [here](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/routes)

Answer (score 0):

in your index file

```
<Route path="/" compoment={Home}
```

if "Navigation" is your class

```
const Navigation = () => {
     return (
       <>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/not-available-primary" component={NotAvaliable}/>
          <Route path="/not-available-Secondary" component={Avaliable}/>
          <Route path="/available-primary" component={Primary}/>
          <Route path="/available-Secondary" component={Secondary}/>
          <Route path="/direct-debit-primary" component={DirectDBB}/>
          <Route path="/direct-debit-secondary" component={DirectDBBSecondary}/>
        </Routes>
      </>
     )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

At the first use `<Switch>` in Navigation component :

```
const Navigation = () => {
   <Switch>
      <Route path="/not-available-primary" component={NotAvaliable}/>
      <Route path="/not-available-Secondary" component={Avaliable}/>
      <Route path="/available-primary" component={Primary}/>
      <Route path="/available-Secondary" component={Secondary}/>
      <Route path="/direct-debit-primary" component={DirectDBB}/>
      <Route path="/direct-debit-secondary" component={DirectDBBSecondary}/>
   </Switch>
  }
```

so, add the component to Route:

```
<BrowserRouter>
<Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
    <Route path="/login" exact component={LoginForm} />
    <Route component={Navigation} />
</Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

It's unclear which version of `react-router-dom` you are *trying* to use. version 4/5 or 6, but you've syntax issues for either. The route rendering the `Navigation` component needs a path with a trailing `"*"` character to be matched at the root/base level so the descendent routes can then also be matched and rendered.

## Using `react-router-dom@5`

Use the `Switch` component instead of the `Routes` component. The `Route` components use the `component` (*or `render` or `children` function props*). The home path `"/"` must ***exactly*** match in order for any other route to be matched when the path isn't exactly `"/"`, e.g. `"/not-available-primary"`.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
    <Route path="*" component={Navigation} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

...

```
const Navigation = () => {
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/not-available-primary" component={NotAvaliable} />
    <Route path="/not-available-Secondary" component={Avaliable} />
    <Route path="/available-primary" component={Primary} />
    <Route path="/available-Secondary" component={Secondary} />
    <Route path="/direct-debit-primary" component={DirectDBB} />
    <Route path="/direct-debit-secondary" component={DirectDBBSecondary} />
  </Switch>
};
```

## Using `react-router-dom@6`

All `Route` components can only be rendered by a `Routes` component or another `Route` component in the case of route nesting. The `Route` component API changed significantly and there is now only a single `element` prop taking a `ReactNode`, a.k.a. JSX, as a value. In RRDv6 all routes are now always exactly matched and use a route ranking system; there is no longer an `exact` prop for `Route` components.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="*" element={<Navigation />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

...

```
const Navigation = () => {
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/not-available-primary" element={<NotAvaliable />} />
    <Route path="/not-available-Secondary" element={<Avaliable />} />
    <Route path="/available-primary" element={<Primary />} />
    <Route path="/available-Secondary" element={<Secondary />} />
    <Route path="/direct-debit-primary" element={<DirectDBB />} />
    <Route path="/direct-debit-secondary" element={<DirectDBBSecondary />} />
  </Routes>
};
```